Error when using package:background_locator/settings/locator_settings.dart
In a dart program, I am trying to use the package:background_locator/settings/locator_settings.dart in order to start the location service in background.
I am getting those errors
But, I am getting those errors : 
The named parameter 'settings' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'settings'.
The named parameter 'androidNotificationSettings' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'androidNotificationSettings'.
The method 'AndroidNotificationSettings' isn't defined for the type '_ZoneTrackingScreenState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'AndroidNotificationSettings'.
The named parameter 'iosSettings' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'iosSettings'.
The method 'IOSSettings' isn't defined for the type '_ZoneTrackingScreenState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'IOSSettings'.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:background_locator/background_locator.dart';
import 'screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:background_locator/location_dto.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:background_locator/settings/locator_settings.dart';

void _startLocationService() async {
    await BackgroundLocator.initialize();
    BackgroundLocator.registerLocationUpdate(
      LocationCallbackHandler.callback,
      settings: LocatorSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.NAVIGATION,
        distanceFilter: 10,
        androidNotificationSettings: AndroidNotificationSettings(
          notificationChannelName: 'Location Tracking',
          notificationTitle: 'Tracking Location in Background',
          notificationMsg: 'PinLoc is active',
          notificationBigMsg: 'Background location tracking is active',
          notificationIconColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        iosSettings: IOSSettings(
          accuracy: LocationAccuracy.NAVIGATION,
          distanceFilter: 10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Can you advise please ?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Consult the documentation on the package you are using. You are trying to set a value for the settings parameter, but there is no settings parameter in the BackgroundLocator.registerLocationUpdate method.
